# Get number of comments within a forum

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

forums, threads, comments

I would like to write a query to get the number of comments within a forum.

Every row in threads has a column "fid" which shows which forum the thread was posted in.

Every row in comments has a column "tid" which shows which thread the comment was posted on.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share anything you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT f.Id, f.Name, COUNT(c.id) AS cnt
FROM forums AS f
LEFT JOIN threads AS t ON f.id = t.fid
LEFT JOIN comments AS c ON t.id = c.tid
GROUP BY f.Id, f.Name
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to get the latest topic in a specific forum by the latest comment posted within the forum?

Comment: @DanielYeffet Yes, there is. But this is a totally different question. You can try writing a new post here in SO.